# IDAPython - Find the start of an undefined code blob

Tags: ida, malware, idapython

I'm currently working on an IDAPython script that aims to remove various rogue-byte from the malware that I'm reversing.

I'm in a case where some portions of my code contain this type of anti-disassembly trick:
[image]

The fact is that without patching the rogue byte, I can't define this undefined blob as a proper function (P shortcut).

So the script is basically doing this:

- Find the following opcode: "*90 C3 FE*" (for "*nop, retn, FE*", FE is the rogue-byte).
- Patch the "FE" byte and replace it by a NOP (*0x90*).
- Define the new NOP as code.

As all the function having this rogue-bytes in it are undefined, I now need to define them as proper function.

But I don't know how to go back to the address of the beginning of the undefined function. For instance, that's the result after executing my IDAPython script:
[image]

The rogue-byte is indeed patch, but now I just need to find the address of "*loc_410687*".

How can I get this address within my IDAPython script?

*(I specify that not all of the function that contains the rogue-byte start by those 3 xors, that's a coincidence. So I can't look for them in order to get the start of the function.)*

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: That's the PonyLoader btw. for which the source got leaked: https://github.com/nyx0/Pony/blob/master/source/PonySrc/Pony.asm Search for "AntiDisasmTrick" - at least in the sourcecode those 3 xors are fixed.

Comment: Yeah, that's indeed a pony sample! That's amazing how you recognize it with only 20 instructions :) Thanks for the source code, it's really helping me

Comment: Did you try to reanalyze program after all patching is done ?

Comment: Yes, I started the analysis even before the rogue-byte things, I'm just trying to make the code cleaner and more pleasant to look at ^^ It even work perfectly in a debugger, the rogue-byte are not affecting anything !